# What trajectory do particles follow in the two-slit experiment in Bohm-de Broglie theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

In Bohm de Broglie interpretation of QM particles have trajectories; in the classic two-slit experiment what trajectories do they follow, and how is the interferance pattern interpreted?

Are particles, for example, guided away by the 'pilot wave' from places of 'destructive interferance'?

Are their trajectories smooth, straight lines or random walks?

Answer (score 1):

See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory#Double-slit_experiment . There are at least two (slightly?) different "subinterpretations" within the de Broglie - Bohm interpretation: in the first one, particles move along the current lines (their trajectories are defined by equations of the first order), in the second one, a force due to the quantum potential acts on the particles defining their trajectories (the trajectories are defined by equations of the second order).